# How to search a text in sublime text 3 with a wildcard between three words?

Tags: regex, search, find, sublimetext3

Basically I have around 100 files that I want to search through.
For example, lets say I have the below text:

```
ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0
ip address 192.168.1.3 255.255.255.0
ip address 192.168.1.4 255.255.255.0
ip address 192.168.1.5 255.255.255.0
ip address 192.168.1.6 255.255.0.0
ip address 192.168.1.7 255.255.0.0
ip address 192.168.1.8 255.255.0.0
ip address 192.168.1.9 255.0.0.0
ip address 192.168.1.10 255.0.0.0
ip address 192.168.1.11 255.0.0.0
ip address 192.168.1.12 255.0.0.0
```

In the above text, I want to search with the middle word being a wildcard. I could easily do this in Notepad ++ using an asterix(*) but unable to make it work with SublimeText 3.

Search Example:

```
ip address * 255.255.255.0
```

where the * can be any word/number.

Please help on this.

Comment: Use `.*` or `.*?`

Comment: I feel so stupid. This helps SO MUCH. Thanks a lot!